# How to make images get cut off

Tags: html, css

http://s1167.photobucket.com/user/unlivedgears/media/image-8.jpg.html?sort=3&o=1

http://s1167.photobucket.com/user/unlivedgears/media/image-9.jpg.html?sort=3&o=0

See On the first image how the girls head and legs are cut off because the image is too long for the square. How can I make it so that it cuts them both off and centers it?  Or if it it too wide it will cut the sides off?

Answer (score 14):

Assuming an HTML structure like this:

```
<div>
    <img />
</div>
```

Use this css:

```
div{
    height: 100px;
    width: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

img{
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

Or, you could set the image as a background image and use `background-size: cover`

Comment: Thank you it worked. But do you know how I could center the image vertically and horizontally?

Comment: @DylanBaker I would suggest setting the image as a background image and using `background-position: center;`