# How can I get the image to show in the img container, using Django template tags?

Tags: python, html, css, django, templates

So I am at the last couple details of my portfolio website, and everything has gone relatively smoothly. I have not had an issue with images before, but this time I am using a {% for loop %} to iterate over the code for the card and I just have the variable template tags that create a new object every time I add something new in the django admin interface.

I feel like there is some small detail I am just completely missing, because I had it working at one point, but then decided to do the iteration instead of hard-coding it in, and it just won't show up. Another pair of eyes would be nice.

This is the section of my index.html:

```
{% block content %}
  {% load static %}

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Jordan Miracle</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/portfolio/style.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <body>


  <div class="jumbotron text-center ui-datepicker-next-hover" style="margin-bottom:0">
    <div class="align-center">
      <img src="{% static 'portfolio/mylogo.png' %}" id="img-bastet" class="img-fluid"
           alt="Jordan and Bastet">
    </div>
    <h1><p style="font-family: 'Ubuntu Mono', Monospaced, monospace; font-size: medium;">Developer and Aspirant Data
      Scientist</p>
  </div>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="https://github.com/jordanmiracle">Github</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="https://twitter.com/jordanmiracle1">Twitter</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/jordan-m-605b4b1a9/">LinkedIn</a>
    </div>
    <div class="topnav-right">
      <a href="{% url 'blog:all_blogs' %}" style="float: right" class="btn btn-secondary">Blog</a>
  </nav>

  <div class="container" style="margin-top:30px">
    <div class="row">
      <h2>About Me</h2>
      <div class="row justify-content-center my-3">
        <div class="col-5" style="border: #303030" aria-setsize="10px">
          <img src="{% static 'portfolio/me-bastet-and-babys-turtle.jpg' %}" class="img-fluid"
               alt="Jordan and Bastet">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="intro-text">
        <p style="font-family: 'Ubuntu Mono', Monospaced, monospace; font-size: small; ">
        <p>I enjoy web development, and have a true love for analyzing data. Whether creating visualizations and
          interpreting what I find,<br>
          or creating a machine learning model to try and make predictions. <br>
          Things that interest me the most are the climate and our ecosystem, consciousness, and the cosmos that we live
          in.
        </p>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
        <div class="button-row-main">
          <button class="nav-button highlight-green">
            <a href="mailto:jordanmiracle&#64;protonmail.com" target="_blank">Contact
              Me</a>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="portfolio">
          {% for project in projects %}
            <div class="project">
              <h2>{{ project.title }}</h2>

              <p class="technologies">
              </p>

              <!-- Depending on availability, display either the image as a link,
                    only image, or a string explaining that the img is missing-->
              {% if project.image %}
              <a href="{{ project.url }}" target="_blank">
                <div class="img-container" style="background-image: url('{{ project.image }}')"></div>
              </a>
              <p>{{ project.description }}
              </p><br>
              <div class="project-links">
                <a href="http://www.mwfarriers.com" target="_blank">Live Site</a>
                <a href="{{ project.code_url }}" target="_blank">Code</a>
              </div>
            {% endif %}
            </div>

          {% endfor %}


  </body>
{% endblock %}
</html>
```

My style.css:

```
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #00FF00;
  color: #303030;
}

/* ---------- HOME ---------- */

/* create color-hover-effect for M logo and buttons */
.highlight-orange:hover {
  color: #417FD5;
  border-color: #ffa000;
}

.highlight-green:hover {
  color: darkred;
  border-color: indianred;
}


button a {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  text-decoration: darkslateblue;
  color: inherit;
  /* increase the clickable area */
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 1.3em;
  margin: -1.3em;
}

.nav-button {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #303030;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: #303030;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
  box-shadow: #417FD5;
}


.button-row-mobile,
.button-row-portfolio-mobile {
  display: none;
}

/* ---------- PORTFOLIO ---------- */

.portfolio {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.project {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 3px solid #303030;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.project-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.project-links a {
  color: #4DAAE3;
}

.project-links a:visited {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.project-links a:hover {
  color: #4DAAE3;
}

.button-row-portfolio {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  bottom: 5px;
}

.button-row-portfolio .nav-button {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

/*
  restrict img to uniform size automatically,
  while showing the center portion of the screenshot. adapted from:
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866223/how-to-make-images-get-cut-off
*/
.img-container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 250px;
  color: transparent;
  background-position: center;
  border: 1px solid #303030;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/* ---------- FOOTER ---------- */

.separator {
  display: none;
}

  #footer {
    position : absolute;
    bottom : 0;
    height : 40px;
    margin-top : 40px;
  }


footer {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #303030;
}

.site-footer {
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: #aa2222;
  color: white;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
}

.icon {
  height: 36px;
  width: auto;
  padding: 8px;
}

.overflow {
  color: #fdfdfd;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

/* ---------- RESPONSIVE ELEMENTS ---------- */

/* TODO: remove blue highlighting when buttons are clicked */
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

  .logo {
    font-size: 14em;
  }

  .button-row-main,
  .button-row-portfolio {
    display: none;
  }

  .button-row-mobile {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }

  .button-row-portfolio-mobile {
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
    bottom: 5px;
  }

  .button-row-portfolio-mobile .nav-mobile {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }

  .nav-mobile {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
  }

  .highlight-orange {
    color: #4DAAE3;
    border-color: #4DAAE3;
    fill: #4DAAE3;
  }

  .highlight-green {
    color: lightgreen;
    border-color: lightgreen;
    fill: lightgreen;
  }

  .highlight-blue {
    color: lightblue;
    border-color: lightblue;
    fill: lightblue;
  }

  .separator {
    display: block;
  }

  footer {
    margin-top: 24px;
  }

  .icon {
    height: 45px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 20px;
  }
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: "Ubuntu Mono", serif;
}

/* Center website */
.main {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.row {
  margin: 8px -16px;
}

/* Add padding BETWEEN each column (if you want) */
.row,
.row > .column {
  padding: 8px;
}

/* Create four equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

/* Clear floats after rows */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Content */
.content {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes a two column-layout instead of four columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .column {
    width: 75%;
  }
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

My models.py:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    image = models.FilePathField(path='portfolio/images')
    url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    code_url = models.URLField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

[Here is my file structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsthl.png)

If anybody needs more information, or if I need to provide more details, just let me know. This is the last thing really standing in my way of deploying and it's been a pain.

[Before changing it to img class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFCAw.png)

[After changing it from a div class to img class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxYSR.png)

Comment: You are trying to display an image inside a div tag; change it to an image tag.

Comment: The <div class immediately before the {{ project.image }}? I just changed it to img class and it did do something. It basically just outlined the img container in the card. I have all the css and everything styled so that it was working before, just with a path. But I can't hard code it in now.

I'll post before and after pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images needed to be registered properly in the Django admin shell.

Once in the shell, I had to import the models.

from portfolio.models import Project

Then, p2 = Project.objects.get(id=2)

p2.image = <path_to_file>

And so on. Once they were registered in the DB, they popped up right away.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might need to set a background image size on `.img-container`. If that doesn't work, also try setting `display: block;`

```css
.img-container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 250px;
  color: transparent;
  background-position: center;
  border: 1px solid #303030;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: I just deleted my previous response. I had tried your two solutions by themselves, but to no avail. However, I was just able to fix it myself. It was an issue with registering the images in the database through the Django shell. I just added the whole file path and the images just popped up right where they were supposed to be.

However, the code you recommended is still in my CSS file, so it may have had something to do with it.

Thanks for taking the time to help out.

Comment: I just checked it out, and the background-size: cover; definitely does help. So thanks for that.